# Android notification icon replaced by green android icon and it doesn't vibrate

Tags: android, push-notification

[UPDATE]
Icon issue has been fixed but still need the notification to vibrate the device.

AndroidManifest permissions

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I'm learning android development and now trying to set a push notification using this code from an answer on stackoverflow

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

public void addNotification(View view){

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        CharSequence name = "my_channel";
        String Description = "This is my channel";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(Description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myappnotificon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Notification body");

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

}
```

Testing on virtual devices it looks good but testing on Android 6 and 7 real devices the icon is replaced with a green icon like the attached image and it doesn't vibrate.

So how to fix the icon issue and make the device vibrate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change **`android:roundIcon`** property in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

There is **default round icon** set in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

You just need to replace it with your icon.
i.e.:

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/your_logo"
```

As the below image you need to set your logo to **`android:icon=`** as well as **`android:roundIcon=`**

- You can set same icon to both properties.

[image]

**Note:** Android 7.1 and afterwards we can set **`android:roundIcon=`** in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

You can get more from [this page.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1#circular-icons)

- For **Vibration issue** this will fix the issue

  ```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
          .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500})
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_app_icon)
          .setContentTitle("Title")
          .setContentText("Notification body");
  ```

And **remove** these lines from **`if`** statement:

```
mChannel.enableVibration(true);
mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working as it should. But what about vibration?

Comment: Glad that my suggestion worked for you. :-) have you declared vibrate permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** ?? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

Comment: yes i did

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

but no vibration

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion helped you. happy coding ;-)